# How do I get the ContactID when using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I'm importing label data from Google Contacts into a spreadsheet and also want the associated photo. I found that the photo can be referenced to with:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactId}
```

I can get the FullName with the code below, but how can I retrieve the contactId? The Contact class does not seem to have this member.

```js
      var primary;
      var fullName = con.getFullName(); // A
      var groups = con.getContactGroups();
      var group;
      if (groups.length > 0) {
        try {
          for (var i2 = 0; i2 < groups.length; i2++) {
            var name = groups[i2].getName();

            if (name.indexOf("Imported") == -1 && name != "") {
              group = name;
              break;
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {}
      } else {
        group = "";
      }
```

Comment: Do you really need this wall of code to ask "how do I get a contact ID"? If you can trim the code down to a [mcve] to focus on the specific problem, it's more likely to get looked at & answered.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.   Hope this is better.

Answer (score 2):

There is a getId() method in the Contact class. You can find the documentation at:

`https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#getId()`

An example:

```
var contact = ContactsApp.createContact('John', 'Doe', 'john.doe@example.com');
var id = contact.getId();
```